# Is it possible to use a v-model from inside a component template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can the v-model syntax be used from inside a Vue component template?

The following works as expected when included directly in an .html

```
<input type="text" v-model="selected_service_shortname">
```

Putting the following stuff into a component template does not work.

```
var service_details = {
    template: `
    ...
    <input type="text" v-model="selected_service_shortname"> 
    ...
`
};


vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        'service-details': service_details
    },
```

Results in `vue.min.js:6 ReferenceError: selected_service_shortname is not defined`

Changing the template syntax to

```
<input type="text" v-model="this.$parent.selected_service_shortname">
```

Seems to halfway work -- changes applied externally to `selected_service_shortname` appear in the input box as expected.  But making changes to the input box directly results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Is what I'm trying to do a supported use case?  If so, are there working examples somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement support for `v-model` in your component. This is covered in the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).

Here is an example.

```
var service_details = {
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
          <input type="text" v-model="internalValue"> 
        `,
  computed: {
    internalValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v)
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Basically, `v-model`, by default, is simply sugar for passing a `value` property and listening for the `input` event. So all you need to do is add a `value` property to your component, and emit an `input` event. This can also be customized as [described in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

```js
console.clear()

var service_details = {
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
          <input type="text" v-model="internalValue"> 
        `,
  computed: {
    internalValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v)
      }
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected_service_shortname: "some service name"
  },
  components: {
    'service-details': service_details
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <service-details v-model="selected_service_shortname"></service-details>
  <hr>
  Selected Service Shortname: {{selected_service_shortname}}
</div>
```

Used in the parent like this:

```
<service-details v-model="selected_service_shortname"></service-details>
```